# How do I add packages to an existing docker container using pipenv

Tags: python, django, docker, docker-compose, pipenv

I currently have a Django app running in a docker container and I want to install additional packages to the container without rebuilding the entire container. I've tried bringing up the container using:

```
docker-compose up
```

then

```
docker-compose exec web pipenv install "package_name_here"
```

what happens is the package installs but I lose it the moment I shut down the container.

How do I persist the installation even after shutting down the container without also rebuilding the entire container?

Comment: The right solution is to add the package install to your Dockerfile and build a new image. However, if you don't want to do that, you can use `docker commit` to create an image from a running container.

Answer (score 0):

Generally a docker container starts from scratch every time you start it. The only way to get persistent data is if you create a volume which then is mounted inside your container but remains persistent in your hosts storage.

You could however start a container and modify it according to your needs (e.g. install your pipenv installation). Then you could use docker commit which is basically a copy of the current system you modified. Then you can change out docker compose file to use this commited image instead of the clean one.